# Set local notification custom sound from assets

Tags: flutter

This is my notification function , **How to set a custom sound from my assets?**

```
Future<void> _repeatNotification() async {
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'repeating channel id',
        'repeating channel name',
        'repeating description',
    );
    var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();
    var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
        androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.periodicallyShow(0, 'Title',
        'Body', RepeatInterval.EveryMinute, platformChannelSpecifics);
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Custom sounds should be set from the native Android and iOS projects. For Android this will be the `raw` folder.

You can play the custom sound by defining its name while instantiating the NotificationDetails

```
AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'repeating channel id',
        'repeating channel name',
        'repeating description',
         sound: 'your_sound_file_name',
    );


IOSNotificationDetails(sound: "your_sound_file_name.aiff")
```

Comment: your_sound_file_name.aiff should be added from XCode

Answer (score 1):

You can play the asset sound through the following property:

```
sound:  const UriAndroidNotificationSound("assets/tunes/pop.mp3"),
```

Worked 100% correctly:

```
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.schedule(
    id,
    "Notification",
    'Notification Alert',
    dateTime,
    NotificationDetails(
      android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          "channel.id",
          "channel.name",
          importance: Importance.max,
          priority: Priority.high,
          color: primaryColor,
          playSound: true,
          sound:  const UriAndroidNotificationSound("assets/tunes/azan.mp3"),
          icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher'
      )
    )
);
```